# Python django, check if sql column contains a value

Tags: python, sql, django

Is there a way to check if a table column already contain a value without using a for loop?

Does django have a "not in" syntax?

Comment: By contain a value do you mean a specific value or just any non null value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this...

```py
# Check for null
YourModel.objects.filter(yourcolumn__isnull=True).all()

# Check for empty string
YourModel.objects.filter(yourcolumn='').all()
```